# Laravel: last migration

Tags: laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-5.7, laravel-migrations

i'm using laravel and working on migrations.
I am looking for records of the implementation of migrations. How does Laravel find out how far the migrations have run? Because I have checked that each migraine only runs once and will not run in subsequent commands.
My software has one source and several databases (per user). I would like to know what effect will this have on other users if one of my users executes migraine?

Comment: check the migration table in your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations, once processed are held in the database in a migrations table.  If your users have separate databases then they will have their own migrations table.  Can't imagine a scenario though where users of the application would be running migrate?

Comment: I have a central database. One of the tables in this database is my users, with their own proprietary database information. When a user enters his address, I inject his database information to Larval. I have also called a method in the main control that executes the artesian command using the artesian class.